# I get a zlib error everytime i import "expo-server-sdk" into my expo app

Tags: android, react-native, expo, zlib, expo-notifications

Everytime I import "expo-server-sdk" into my app I get this an error "undefined Unable to resolve module ./zlib_bindings from `/home/duke/Code/rete/node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js`:

None of these files exist:

- node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib_bindings(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
- node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib_bindings/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)

> 1 | module.exports = require('./zlib_bindings');
> |                           ^
> 2 |"

I really don't know what to do anymore please can anyone help?